# Is it possible to run multiple instances of Skype?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, skype, sony-xperia-l

In windows I'm using multiple accounts of Skype simultaneously using MultiSkype Launcher. Is there any way that I can use multiple Skype accounts or at least two accounts simultaneously without switching between them. I'm using unrooted Xperia L with Android Jellybean. I can't root my phone. Is there any solution? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With ApkEditor you can recompile an app with another package ID, allowing it to be installed in parallel with normal version

Comment: I was able to install a second instance of Skype with APK Editor Pro by editing both the provider and the package name, but the second instance would randomly freeze and crash very quickly. I'm not sure why.